# Dot product and Cross Product of Matrices in Jama

Tags: java, android, jama

I am using Jama in android.
Given two matrices how would you perform the dot product and cross product in Jama?
I came across [this](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~eeaton/software/Utils/javadoc/edu/umbc/cs/maple/utils/JamaUtils.html#dotproduct) but uncertain how to implement it.

Comment: how the matrices can contain dot product and cross products? are you talking about vectors?

Comment: No, I am talking about Matrices.